# Cannot take the address of the result of append

Tags: go

I got this error "Cannot take the address of the result of append" when I try to :

```
s := []int{1, 2}
temp := &s
temp = &append(*temp, 3)
```

but if I make minor change like this:

```
s := []int{1, 2}
temp := &s
temp2 := append(*temp, 3)
temp = &temp2
```

there is no error.

I was navigated to this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1338), but I can't understand it's comments.

Can anyone explain the differences?

Comment: You say "I got this error", but you never mention an error.

Comment: If you can understand the comments in the linked issue, what's the problem?

Answer (score -2):

In the second example you take the reference to the copy of the append function thats why you do not get a compiler error but it should not wor either. In the first example you try to get the reference directly to the append function thats why you get a compiler error

Comment: thanks buddy, how can I directly dereference the returned value without help of a middle variable like 2nd example

Comment: I think that you do not need the reference of the append function but just the value it returns but thats something you should look up in the g documentation

Comment: *In the second example you take the reference to the copy of the append function* No. He's taking the address of `temp2` which is perfectly valid.